# Guava library duplicate entry error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-guava

I am trying to use [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library in my application. But I am also using [chromium_webview](https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview) project from github.  This webview project contains guava library.

And I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. java.util.zip.ZipException:
>   duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/GwtIncompatible.class

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878676/transformexception-duplicate-entry-for-common-annotations-beta?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984426/android-studio-multiple-dex-files-gradle-error?answertab=votes#tab-top) answers already and nothing seems to work.

Here's my module's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        jumboMode = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/svgAndroid2-3Jan2014.jar')
    compile project(':chromium_webview')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

I've tried the exclude method on the `chromium_webview` project like this:

```
compile (project(':chromium_webview')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: "guava_javalib.jar"
}
```

and like this:

```
compile (project(':chromium_webview')) {
    exclude module: "guava_javalib.jar"
}
```

Can I not use the same library again?
Is there a way to use the same library for both modules?

// ======================= EDIT:

Like @petey's comment mentioned, I tried removing just the guava library from my module and my module doesn't read the library in another module.

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
```

that's the line I tried removing.

Any ideas will be really appreciated.
Thank you!!

Comment: cant you just delete `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'`? since its already part of the chromium_webview dependencies?

Comment: I tried that. When i build it, my module (application) can't find the library

Comment: Did you happen to fix this problem? I have the same exact issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did fix this problem, forgot to post it.

So the issue here was I was using maven/gradle dependency in my project BUT the `chromium_webview` library was using an actual JAR file as a library.

I modified the library to use the maven/gradle dependency.  Android Studio and Gradle did all the work for me and excluded the necessary classes.

So make sure they both (library and your module) use the same method.
`compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'`

I really hope this helps someone.
Thank you.